# display data in multiple columns with for loop

Tags: django

I'm sure this is a simple answer but for the life of me I cant figure / find out how to go about this.

I want to display blog posts from my data base in three equal columns.
When I start looking into the bootstrap docs this is the code given.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However If I go to implement it I dont understand how i would be able to put the for loop on it without it repeating everything 3 times. IE:

```
        {% for post in posts.all %}      
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image.url  }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image.url  }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image.url  }}" />
            </div>
        </div>                           
        {% endfor %}
```

If you could please point me in the right direction on how to go about this it would be very much appreciated bootstrap is not a requirement.

Comment: Please include the related view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view should "prepare" the data to make it easy to enumerate over this. We can create chunks with:

```
def some_view(request):
    posts = list(Post.objects.all())
    posts = [posts[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(posts), 3)]
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'products': products})
```

in the template we can then work with a double [**`{% for … %}…{% endfor %}`** loop [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for chunk in posts %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for post in chunk %}
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image.url  }}" />
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```